# How to create a MapView with a specific ID?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I know it is possible to create a map with `Bukkit.getServer().createMap(Bukkit.getWorld("world"));` however this will create a map with the first available id. Lets say I want to create a map with the id 10000. When I try to use `Bukkit.getServer().getMap(10000);` it returns null because this map doesn't exist.

How to create a MapView with a specific ID?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this function? Going NMS is never recommended

Comment: @Kerooker I'm creating a display with pictures that refreshes every minute. I don't want to risk overwriting other maps. I chose 10000 because user generated maps probably never reach that id. Also, why don't you recommend NMS? Is it because it can break between versions or is it because of something else?

Comment: Can break between versions and is hard to implement correctly performance-wise

Comment: I would recommend instead creating a new World, an empty, unloaded and inaccessible and create maps from there. The ID generated would be empty, and you wouldn't overwrite maps

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but it works:

```
import net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.WorldMap;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.WorldServer;

public static MapView createMap(World world, int id) {
    WorldServer ws = ((CraftWorld) world).getHandle();
    String name = "map_" + id;
    WorldMap map = new WorldMap(name);
    map.scale = 3;
    map.a(ws.getWorldData().b(), ws.getWorldData().d(), map.scale);
    map.map = (byte) ws.dimension;
    map.c();
    ws.getServer().getServer().worlds.get(0).a(name, map);
    MapInitializeEvent event = new MapInitializeEvent(map.mapView);
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(event);
    return map.mapView;
}
```

Only tested on Spigot 1.11.2 but this method should work on some other versions. I just modified the NMS existing code to use a custom ID.

This is pretty low level NMS so I wouldn't be surprised if this method no longer works a few updates from now.

Comment: This will just makes a map with the next available ID like it would do if you use `Bukkit.getServer().CreateMap(world);`

Comment: @nelson2tm Try this. It works for me on 1.11.2 but you'll have to test it each time you update.